# Where is guiclient.conf located?

Tags: plasticscm

The [latest release notes](http://%22https://www.plasticscm.com/download/releasenotes/5.4.16.644%22) state:

> PlasticDrive can also be launched from the changesets menu of the
>   Windows GUI. In order to enable you have to edit your guiclient.conf
>   file and add the following line:  > `<ShowMountPlasticDrive>true</ShowMountPlasticDrive>`

But I don't have a guiclient.conf file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I bet you have one :-) Just look here:

```
c:\users\<your-name>\AppData\Local\plastic4\guiclient.conf
```

Here's mine:

```
C:\Users\pablo\AppData\Local\plastic4>type guiclient.conf | grep Drive
  <ShowMountPlasticDrive>true</ShowMountPlasticDrive>
```

The feature is pretty experimental yet, but should be fully usable. It is an improved "glassfs" which has been there for quite a long time, but with some tweaks to make it more usable.

It is very useful to take a look at the code using your Visual Studio without switching branches (although the first time you launch it it will be slow, since VS reads all the files in the solution, but then they're cached and next run will fly!).